# Как в качестве буфера ReadFile использовать string?

Tags: c++, winapi

У меня есть необходимость использовать в качестве принимающего буфера string, но ReadFile ругается что не может преобразовать из string в LPVOID

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    int fileSize = 0;
    std::string tempBuff = 0;
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA("C:\\Users\\user\\q.txt", GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, 0);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    fileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, 0);
    if (fileSize == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    DWORD numBuff;
    if (ReadFile(hFile, tempBuff, fileSize, &numBuff, 0) == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Могу ли я как то использовать string или обязательно использовать char?

Comment: Можно привести указатель на первый символ к (LPVOID), однако всё равно придётся заранее установить длину строки, ведь в нераспределённый буфер читать не получится. Откуда вообще такая нужда - использовать высокоуровневые типы для низкоуровневых операций?

Comment: @Mbo Мне нужно прочитать файл и нужные мне данные записать в другой файл с помощью `WriteFile` но у WriteFile 2-м параметром нужно задать `LPCVOID` что так-же мне не подходит ведь изначально я использова вместо `std::string tempBuff`  `char* tempBuff` и не мог совершить запись в файл, я подумал что смогу прочитать файл и вывести все в буфер типа string, а дальше совершить запись с помощью `WriteFile`

Comment: Трудности надуманные, с char* и приведением типов всё получится. Однако у Вас текстовый файл. Почему бы не воспользоваться специальными средствами для текстовых файлов? fstream cin cout

Comment: @MBo да изначально я использовал реализацию с помощью fstream но сейчас я пытаюсь лишь убавить размер своего файла с помощью winapi

Comment: тогда убирайте и string. конструкция `std::string tempBuff = 0;` радует:)

Comment: А в чем проблема читать в буфер на стеке, и сразу писать его в другой файл? Пока есть данные..

Comment: да вот тоже думаю. человек хочет отказаться от с++ (но при этом боится сказать, что он хочет использовать добрый чистый си) , но не знает, как это сделать. `char tempBuff[10...00]`  и поехали (главное, что бы хватило). А строка `ReadFile(hFile, tempBuff, fileSize, &numBuff, 0)` - это уже неверно, учитывая, что string tempBuff имеет нулевой размер....